# Pareto two-tailed GLM regression

Tags: generalized-linear-model, nonlinear-regression, pareto-distribution

How can I perform a Pareto two-tailed GLM regression? Any reference to link functions and code in R?

Comment: Is a (two-tailed?) Pareto even a member of the GLM family? (If your question is only about obtainable software, it is quite possibly off-topic here.)

Comment: What do you mean a member? It's an exponential distribution and I know there are estimators for the two-Tailed version. What I'm looking for is a GLM link function.

Comment: Do you mean the Pareto mentioned in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_family#Table_of_distributions or some other distribution? Are you seeking to identify which link function (mathematical sense) is appropriate or looking for link function code (software sense)? If negative or zero values are possible, then I'd guess that the link is just identity.

Comment: Yes to both Questions.